# Add value to databound dropdown list

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

Hi I am populating a drop down list from an sql table, I would like to add an item that says 'Select Status' as the initial text field with no value to help prompt selecting a value from the drop down, how can I add this in?

```
statusConn.Open();
        ddlStatus.DataSource = statusCMD.ExecuteReader();
        ddlStatus.DataTextField = "Project_Status_Name";
        ddlStatus.DataValueField = "Project_Status_ID";
        ddlStatus.DataBind();
        statusConn.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just insert it as a first item after the data binding:

```
ddlStatus.DataBind();
statusConn.Close();

ddlStatus.Items.Insert(0, "Select Status");
```